# What is the best way to query Spark application state and kill it on demand programatically?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Can you please advice me what is the best way to query spark application state submitted to yarn and kill it on demand? Both programatically.

What I want to do:
I need to expose simple ui which will monitor submitted spark applications - their state, time running and provide capability to kill it on demand.

I was hoping I could do something like this (from java):

- submit spark application to yarn with some id
- get list of spark applications submitted to yarn
- kill an application specifying id

Whereas submitting spark application from java code is simple I found it confusing how to query its state and kill it.

I understand that I would be able to achieve this using:

- spark-jobserver
- Resource manager REST API

via REST which would suffice me.

My question is - is there another simple way? Is it possible to do it directly from java code using yarn/spark java libraries? Or what is the recommended way to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: I usually just use yarn's CLI to kill a job `yarn application -kill <application_id>`, and the resource manager web interface to see what is currently running. Likely, you can get the java API to accomplish those tasks from the source of those tools directly.